# Как пишется слово хорошопроходимый

Tags: орфография

Как  пишется слово  хорошопроходимый вместе или раздельно?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **хорошо проходимый**.

**Наречия могут соединяться с прилагательными, образуя термины,** но существование данного термина надо проверять по словарю. Например для наречия "легко" указано: **ЛЕГКО**... **Первая часть сложных слов.** 1. Обозначает лёгкость осуществления какого-л. действия.  легкодоступный, легкоуправляемый, легкоусвояемый. 2. Обозначает сниженную, облегчённую оснащённость чем-л., каким-л. качеством.  легковооружённый.

**А для наречия "хорошо" такой информации нет,** поэтому  существует только словосочетание "хорошо проходимый", и синонимичные выражения хорошо проходимый и легкопроходимый пишутся по-разному.

**В то же время термины могут легко "распадаться" на исходные слова и писаться раздельно**, что определяется, к примеру,  наличием зависимых слов или стилем речи (специальная литература или общего характера). Поэтому можно встретить различные варианты написания для  "легкопроходимый".

**Примеры:**

Очень удобная коляска, **хорошо проходимая,** вместительная, многофункциональная. Тропинка, идущая по насыпи, **хорошо проходима.**

Там ещё остался **легкопроходимый** битый лед. Северная часть горной системы сравнительно невысока , имеются **легкопроходимые** перевалы. Туристы с хода преодолевают **легкопроходимый** порог "Морской".

С высоты тундр опять спустились **в легко проходимый лес.**

Answer (score 0):

Нет в словарях такого слова. Нужно писать **хорошо проходимый**.